# What Rav do majority of Sefardi Jews follow(ed) on 2010?

Tags: rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Which rabbi do the majority of [sefardim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephardi_Jews) follow? Or, do a majority of them not follow a single rabbi?

*As of May 3, 2010*

Comment: I edited this as 6 years later things change.

Answer (score 13):

There is no one simple answer for this; however, if you had to pick the one biggest name among Sefardi rabbis living today, that would be [Rabbi Ovadia Yosef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovadiah_Yosef), [shlit'a](http://www.torah.org/qanda/seequanda.php?id=337).

While not all Sefardim follow him all the time, his word is definitely given a great deal of weight.  Is that who you had in mind?

The Shulchan Aruch (written about 450 years ago) is usually used as a framework for Halacha today.  Within it, Ashkenazim usually follow the notes of R' Moshe Issreles, but Sefardim follow its primary author, R' Yosef Karo.

Comment: Although, when R' Moshe Isserles (Rema) comes to add and not to argue, the Sefardim often go like his ruling as well.

Comment: The Ben Ish Chai, or Baba Sali are referred to much more often than R. Karo.

Comment: In a **halachic** context (check the tag on this question), it's Shulchan Aruch. R' Ovadya Yosef shlit'a has insisted that real Sephardic psak has to stem from there, and that Sephardic practice over the years has been corrupted by outside influences, including Kabbalistic ones.

Comment: Shalom is correct. Although the Ben Ish Hai is cited a lot, the S"A is cited much more. Also, the Baba Sali never wrote a book on Halacha (as far as I know) so I don't see how he could be quoted.

Comment: Rav Ovadia Yosef is from the biggest in our generation, Sephardi or Ashkanazi.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Shalom, Rav Ovadia would probably be called the "Sefardi rav." Other Sefardi rabbis that people also follow such as:

- Rav Mordechai Eliyahu (who passed away very recently 1-2 years ago);
- Rav BenSion Aba Shaul (passed away 1998);
- Rav BenSion Musafi Shelita;
- Rav Shelomo Amar (Sephardic Chief rabbi);
- Rav Eliyahu Bakshi Doron (former chief Rabbi);
- Chacham Yosef Harari-Raful (Moeset HaGedola in USA); and
- Rav Meir Mazuz.

Comment: Also Chacham Yosef Harari-Raful, I think....

Comment: Indeed, in america, he is actually on the Moeset HaGedola.

Comment: @msh210 also Rav Meir Mazuz.

Comment: @Yehoshua thats `talmid` chacham